# How to design the A-B amplifier? I mean I have understood the working but how do i choose the values?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, power-electronics

We have a college project to make an A-B amplifier. I have a basic layout of the transistor amplifier. Plus i have chosen the transistors I want. There are : 2N4401 (NPN) and 2N4403 (PNP).

1)My source is a song being played from my mobile. Here I have taken an AC Voltage of 16pk.
2) How do I modify my circuit for it.I realised Higher the Vcc value I take, the output increases more. Why? And what would be the ideal value?
3)Have I selected the wrong diodes? If I have so which one is suitable for the transistors I have chosen?
4)Why is my positive output waveform increasing with each increasing second?Also why is my Ie of npn decreasing?

[image: Finally]

EDIT 1: I Have changed the circuit after comparing it more carefully with the suggestions other users have given me. The Schematic is attached below with the output. I noticed other users complaining that my questions have been made blindly. Hence, I have been more precise now.
My Input here is a song being played from my mobile/smartphone. I will connect to the amplifier using it's audio jack. Thus, the song will be played on the speaker (here RL).
Firstly, when I make it on a breadboard the input here will be the song right? So, will the song even play (w/t distortion). Cause, Here I have taken a sine wave input and according to the simulation it is just increasing the amplitude.
Secondly, As pointed out by @jock my knowledge of the amplifier design is limited. I have seen probably all the videos relating to this amplifier on youtube . So, I know it's working but I am really confused about how to design one. Is there anywhere I can read up on this?
[image]

Comment: There are many sets of values that will work here.  To narrow it down, what is the value of RL and what power are you hoping to get there?  So the first step to choosing the values it to know the output specification of the amp.

Comment: @owg60 hi, I have kept RL as a speaker with 8 ohm resistance and 10W is the output power i want.

Comment: If you mean 10Wrms, (into 8 ohms) you're stuck already, you don't have enough supply voltage.

Comment: @BrianDrummond This is a random pic on the net. However this is my layout. Like i said in my question I am unable to calculate any of the values of RL. Isn't there any kind of procedure I have to follow for finding the values of this Amp.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have changed the question.

Comment: You need to provide more specifications about where you are eventually headed. It's a lot easier to show you a design process for a specific design than to provide design instructions that incorporate all someone has learned across outputs spanning from mW to kW. You haven't even bothered to indicate, and for a stage where output power IS usually the starting point (though it's possible that the voltage rails are, instead), the output power delivered into the speaker.

Comment: @jonk I have given my main goal in the Question (1). What I want is to play a somg from my mobile on a speaker of 8 ohm.

Comment: By "mobile" you mean the "headphone" output of a smart phone? Is that really 16V peak-to-peak? Do you have any specification on the power supply/rails? Do you have any specification on the power output you'd like? Or is all that simply left open?

Comment: Why did you remove all if the other information?  You made the answers you already had invalid.  Put the original stuff back and add the new stuff.

Comment: @Jonk It is interesting what he is trying to do and he is willing to learn. Let us help him with practical guidance. Go back to the past and remember that designing an amplifier for the first time was not simple.

Comment: @Decapod I'd like it confirmed this is a headphone jack and I'd like some basic thoughts about what kind of power supply happens to be handy, or if he's willing to construct one from some other design goal. I'm not sure how to guide there. I can mention that headphones are often around \$32\:\Omega\$, though they can be less or more, and that mobile power supplies probably don't deliver more than a few volts RMS into them. Perhaps I shouldn't have used "specification" and simply said, "Tell me more, in plain language, what you want." But he said "design", too. And there some expectation there.

Comment: @Decapod More than glad to help as I can, though.

Comment: You have the two biasing diodes facing each other thus not creating the correct biasing arrangement for the transistors. May I strongly advise you to put in your question precisely what your aims are. DO NOT expect folk to rummage around in comments here and there for this information. Crap in = crap out. Just do it properly if you want to learn and try not to let your question evolve ANY more. This is not a forum, it's a question and answer service with strict guidelines.

Comment: @Andyaka The schematic was drawn so helter-skelter I completely missed that detail! Nice catch.

Comment: There is no such thing as an 'AC voltage of 16pk'. Voltages are measured in volts. Do you mean 16 *volts* peak? And how are you planning to get that from a mobile device, that don't have +/-32V power supplies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said the following that I ***can*** understand, regarding the design:

- Accept mobile output. (Which I can only assume means "headphone" jack.)
- Use 2N4401 and 2N4403 for output BJTs. (That's specific enough.)
- Class AB amplifier (using a complementary emitter follower topology, taken as a specification gathered from your schematic.)

You've said the following that I ***cannot*** understand, regarding the design:

- "mobile" and "AC Voltage of 16pk" -- "Mobile" usually means "headphone" output, to me. But headphones are typically \$32\:\Omega\$, mostly resistive, and generally you don't see more than perhaps \$1.5\:\textrm{V}_{RMS}\$ there. Certainly, I can't recall ever seeing anything like \$16\:\textrm{V}_{PEAK}\$. Your AC simulation voltage source is set up that way. But I can't for the life of me guess why. Are you expecting some prior stage to provide that kind of signal? Where did this come from, exactly?

> 1. My source is a song being played from my mobile. Here I have taken an AC Voltage of 16pk.

I don't understand much of this. See above.

> 2. How do I modify my circuit for it?

By designing it, first.

> 3. I realised Higher the Vcc value I take, the output increases more. Why?

Outputs often increase when they have access to increased voltage rail magnitudes.

> 4. And what would be the ideal value?

In practice, it's a matter of compromise.

> 5. Have I selected the wrong diodes? If I have so which one is suitable for the transistors I have chosen?

Lots of options. One is to use diode connected BJTs. Another is diodes. In either case, you may also want to add a resistor. You could also use a VBE multiplier, with or without Early Effect compensation. In most cases where more power is involved, you may want to thermally couple them. In this case, it perhaps matters not so much.

> 6. Why is my positive output waveform increasing with each increasing second?

Not sure what you are noticing, even with the new diagram.

> 7. Also why is my Ie of npn decreasing?

Not sure that curve is present, either.

---

From the datasheets on the BJTs you've selected, these are TO-92 packaging (which is anywhere from \$200\:\tfrac{^\circ \textrm{C}}{\textrm{W}}\$ to \$325\:\tfrac{^\circ \textrm{C}}{\textrm{W}}\$ -- and I'm not talking about SOT-23 here.) This basically means they can't dissipate much. Even with just \$100\:\textrm{mW}\$, you may see internal temperatures at anywhere from \$20\:^\circ \textrm{C}\$ to \$30\:^\circ \textrm{C}\$ rise over ambient. And that's only \$100\:\textrm{mW}\$.

You will need to reserve about \$1.2\:\textrm{V}\$ to keep both the NPN and the PNP in their active and not saturated regions. Assuming you were willing to run your BJTs at \$50\:^\circ \textrm{C}\$ over ambient (about a \$\tfrac{1}{5}\:\textrm{W}\$ each) you still probably wouldn't get any better than \$150\:\textrm{mW}\$ into an \$8\:\Omega\$ speaker when using the \$5\:\textrm{V}\$ rail that such an output power requires. That's how inefficient this design is likely to be.

Are you prepared for the paltry output that using these BJTs would normally imply?

(Also, as a side question that will rise up later on, how do you expect to handle the stereo output from your mobile? Will you select just one side or the other or do you require summing of the two channels into one?)

Comment: @DeathstrokeTwelved Despite that, perhaps I may yet look forward to seeing an improved question and the chance to fully revise my answer as appropriate.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @DeathstrokeTwelved Just noticed. I changed my reply and added some questions at the end.

Comment: I will make two circuits one for the left audio signal and one for the right audio signal. Though, could it possible if we could get a mono output from a stereo input? Also, can't I run the transistor at 25°C (room temperature) Won't the power dissipated be more at 25°?

Comment: @DeathstrokeTwelved You can make two separate circuits or you can combine the inputs into one mono output. Different things to do. But either approach can be achieved with effort and thought. You misunderstand me about the temperature. The BJTs will, by themselves, heat up. They will get hot. Sure, run them at room temperature. But their temperature will rise. How much depends on just how hard you work them and how you arrange air circulation. Their internal temp will be a lot higher than their surface temp. Just happens. If you want them cooler, you get bigger BJTs and/or add heat sinks.

Answer (score 0):

To start with I propose to feed the transistors not from in between the two biasing diodes thereby preventing signal distortion due to the diode properties.
This is only a little change and does not influence on the calculations. The -VCC is not marked in the picture.

[image]

First a simple verification of the requirements and the limits of the transistors.

You have a supply voltage of 12 Volt. Consider the input signal as a simple sinewave. The peak value of the sine wave can not be more then 12V. Forget about the little details for the moment.

So the RMS value is more or less 8,5V 
Apart from the transistor limitations and other details your power limits already at 9W.

Now we look at the transistors.

Look in the datasheet for the max ratings of the transistors. From there you can calculate the max. allowable power and transistor dissipation. Keep a close eye on the limits. Max current is mostly to much your max power is also to be taken into consideration.

From here try first and come back with questions showing what you have done.

Taking a look at the new schematic.

First of all you are making it more difficult for yourself than you should.
Keep the output transistors NPN / PNP whith the emitors directing towards the load. Also for now do away with the output capacitor and use a symetric input voltage. Keep the system symetrical. And then look at the simulated output again and find the limitations.

Taking a look at the comments.

Read the comments and respond to them by updating your question. Do not remove history. Show the progress.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I have decided to reduce my speaker to a 0.5W and 8ohms. The maximum Power rating of the 2N4401 is 1.5W (datasheet). I have considered Vcc to be around 8V. Are the values I have taken are fine?

Comment: Show what you have done with how and why. Adjust your question and come back. Just asking through comment is not going to work.

Comment: Decapod, Here is The Link: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/267591/a-b-amplifier-doubts-in-design

Comment: I changed the question itself.:)

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: See next update

Comment: @DeathstrokeTwelved take note of my comment under your question dude.

Comment: @Andyaka don't worry man, I read everything;). Decapod, Thanks again for your suggestions!:)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I go about the calculations?

The procedure is this: -

Decide what you want the output load to be (speaker load impedance value) and what (reasonably) undistorted sinewave power you want delivered to it. From those numbers the power rails can be decided upon and then you have a choice - split rails and no bulky output capacitor or a single rail (and 0V) with a bulky output capacitor.

When you have got this far you have to possibly recognize the limitations in your original choice of output transistors. This may cause you to go back to square 1 and re-state what you want.

Once all this is cleared up, an EE would try to work out how high the push-pull emitter resistor values can be to get the specified full power output. A higher value emitter resistor ultimately reduces output distortion and reduces the possibility of thermal runaway.

Then it's just a case of seeing what the current gains of the output transistor will be (under full load) and choosing R1 and R2 to provide enough bias current through the diodes to get low cross-over distortion. Adding another diode in series with the existing two is not unheard of.

At some point in the process, it is possible, that to achieve your design aims, it will be better to use a darlington configuration for your output transistors. Nobody can advice this yet.

It might also be necessary to use a technique known as boot-strapping in order to maximize signal output level. Nobody can advise this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your scope traces look like you have some issues to deal with.  This video on Vbe multipliers will help you [Vbe multiplier and class B output](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Obh_PIC2qqo).  The problem with using diodes to offset the Vbe of the output transistors is that they will never have the transistors and diodes will never have the same current going through them.  Although the diode curve is very steep it will has a slight voltage difference with current that you need to take care of.

Comment: Just noticed Q2 has emitter and collector reversed.